# In Jamaican English, why is there no θ sound?

Tags: pronunciation, accent, sounds

For example, *three* is pronounced as "tree," and *thing* is pronounced as "ting." How come Jamaicans do not have a θ sound in their accents?

Comment: Relatively few languages include that phoneme—Modern Greek and English for two. For those whose mother tongues lack it, the interdental fricative can be among the last and most difficult acquisitions in the learning of spoken English—witness Henry Kissinger. On the flip side, the German back-rolled R may never be acquired even by those non-Germans who gain full German fluency otherwise.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: I will attest to your point about the German. I have lived in Germany and spoke the language pretty well at one time, but I could never ever even pronounce my own name correctly with the back-rolled R in it. The best I could do made it sound more like French.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, every language has its own inventory of sounds.  English has a relatively high number of different sounds, and many of its sounds are rare in the languages of the world (the English "r" sound, for example, is very uncommon).  When a word is borrowed into a new language (or a new dialect), it sometimes gets absorbed into the closest sounds in that target dialect.  At some point, that just becomes the "correct" way to say something.  In this case, it sounds like the voiceless interdental fricative just got moved to [t] (which is much more common across languages).

Comment: I use the term "correct" loosely -- at some point it becomes a question of whether something is an "accent" or a distinct dialect of English (as with English as spoken in, say, India or Singapore).

Answer (score 2):

There are some versions of Jamaican English that contain the 'th' fricative. However, the phonology of Jamaican English is heavily influenced by the phonology of Jamaican Creole. Jamaican Creole has its origin with the people taken from Africa to be slaves in sugar and coffee plantations. Since African languages did not contain the 'th' fricative neither does Jamaican Creole and neither do some varieties of Standard Jamaican English.